# Manipulate matrix without for loops in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, matrix, vectorization

I'm working in Matlab. I have a colored image in a matrix called im1. I need to make all black pixels as white without altering other pixels. How can I do this without for loop?
This code takes a good 10s to execute on a large image.

```
for i=1:h
for j=1:w
    if im1(i,j,:)==0
        im1(i,j,:)=255;
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of two approaches using logical indexing.

Approach 1 -

```
im1(repmat(all(im1==0,3),[1 1 size(im1,3)]))=255
```

Approach 2 -

```
im1(bsxfun(@and,all(im1==0,3),im1==0))=255
```

It would be interesting to see which one is more efficient.

Comment: thanks :) Both take almost the same time. repmat is a tad faster but nothing much..

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
[height, width, dim_3] = size(im1);
[row col] = find(im1(:,:,1) == 0 & im1(:,:,2) == 0 & im1(:,:,3) == 0);
im1(sub2ind([height, width, dim_3],repmat(row,dim_3,1),repmat(col,dim_3,1),repmat((1:dim_3)',numel(row),1))) = 255;
```

Comment: @user1727119 `im1(im1 == 0) = 255` will remove black pixels as well as pixels which have zero intensity in any of the red or green or blue dimension e.g. pure red pixels. Do you want this ?

Comment: @user1727119 I am sorry ,I know this code is incorrect , I am working on it , correct version will be up in very soon.

Comment: @user1727119 , check it out now , notify me for any errors,again sorry for the wrong answer :)

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ltrhc4&s=8 this is the desired output and this is what the code did http://i57.tinypic.com/i6bj9h.jpg

Comment: background is what i'm working on.. from black to white

Comment: @Divakar Thanks this works.. how about put this as the answer?

Comment: @Divakar i can't understand why my solution didn't work for OP, it essentially does the same as yours just takes a longer route but it is working fine on my machine

Comment: @Nishant Yes essentially it's the same as yours, so I would let you add that comment code to your solution. Hope that's okay by the asker. BTW what you are using isn't logical indexing I believe. +1 for efforts

Comment: @Divakar It is your answer and of course a better answer so I think, you should consider adding it as you deserve the credits for it